# How to restrict Mapshaper's `-dissolve` to merge only certain specified features on a layer

Tags: mapshaper

I'm try to merge a few specified features on a topojson map using Mapshaper. For this example, I'm trying to merge Somalia, Somaliland and Puntland to match a dataset that doesn't separate them.

Mapshaper has command features, `-dissolve` and `-dissolve2`, that seem to do what I want. However, they seem to apply to every feature in the selected layer, and I can't see any obvious way [in the Mapshaper docs](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Command-Reference#-dissolve2) to select only certain features within a layer to apply to.

The options `name` and `target` apply to files and layers respectively, not features. Likewise all the usage examples I can find don't select specific features to merge.

There's a feature to limit it by field:

> Name of a data field to dissolve on.

... but I can't find any way to pipe in a list of field values. I can specify the name field, but can't find a way to specify that the name field should be "Somalia" or "Somaliland".

If possible, I'd prefer not to move the features onto a temporary dummy layer then move them back again.

Ideally I'd use something similar to how `-each` and `-filter` allow to match by an expression but that doesn't seem to exist for `-dissolve`. For example, this, which works perfectly for `-filter`, doesn't work:

```
 -dissolve '(NAME == "Somaliland" || NAME == "Puntland" || NAME == "Somalia")'
```

...because that parameter must be a field name and can't be an expression:

> Data table is missing field: (NAME == "Somaliland" || NAME == "Puntland"  || NAME == "Somalia")

Answer (score 1):

This works for `-dissolve`, but doesn't merge the selected features with `-dissolve2`.

---

Essentially, you can edit or create a field using `-each` so that every feature has a different value except the ones you want merged, then, dissolve on that field. This is complicated a little by two things:

- Your dummy field needs to be defined for all features on this layer, else `-dissolve` will fail:

  > Data table is missing field: someFieldName
- Dissolve erases all feature data fields except the one you dissolve on, including FID, unless you expressly tell it not to.

---

So, there are a few steps:

1. Choose a field where each feature has a different unique value, where you can overwrite it for the features that are to be resolved. For example, in my data, let's say every feature has a unique `NAME` and I am merging `NAME=Somaliland` and `NAME=Puntland` into `NAME=Somalia`

   - If for any reason such a field doesn't exist already, you can create a dummy one and use the inbuilt MapShaper ID to give it a unique value. So for example if there's no suitable field and `NAME` is undefined:

     > ```
     > -each 'NAME=this.id'
     > ```
2. Run an `-each` command to give the features you want to target the same value:

   > ```
   > -each 'NAME="Somalia"' where='(NAME == "Puntland" || NAME == "Somaliland")'
   > ```

   - Or if no such field existed before and you created a dummy field, in the Mapshaper UI you can find the ID numbers by clicking on the `i` button then clicking on the features of interest to look up their ID numbers and target them that way:

     > ```
     > -each 'NAME="Somalia"' where='(NAME == "5" || NAME == "8" || NAME == "9")'
     > ```
3. Run a `-dissolve` specifying this field and specifying which field data to keep.

   > -dissolve NAME copy-fields='some,field,names,here'

   The field used to dissolve on is copied automatically. There doesn't seem to be any "copy all option". Also note that:

   > `copy-fields=` Fields to copy when dissolving (comma-sep. list). Copies values **from the first feature in each group of dissolved features**.

   ...so check the values are what you want and if they aren't, you might need to do some more `-each`s to make sure the right field values are the ones the final merged feature gets.