# How to target multiple specific layers when using -merge-layers

Tags: mapshaper

As part of trying to find an answer for [How to -explode only one subfeature from only one feature?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234815/how-to-explode-only-one-subfeature-from-only-one-feature) I created some fields in one layer only, then, after doing some operations, tried to merge that layer back with one other specific layer.

[The docs for `merge-layers`](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Command-Reference#-merge-layers) say you can use `target=` and `name=` but I've not managed to get either to work:

- Apparently `target=` can accept a comma-separated list of layers, but it seems not to work:

  - If I wrap each layer name in quotes:

    > ```
    > -merge-layers target="'layer A', 'layer B'"
    > ```

    ...I get an error suggesting it's looking for one layer called `'layer A', 'layer B'`:

    > Missing target: 'layer A', 'layer B'
    >
    > Available layers: *[list of layers here]*
  - If I *don't* wrap each layer name in quotes:

    > ```
    > -merge-layers target="layer A, layer B"
    > ```

    ... then I get no errors, but nothing happens. It doesn't merge the layers.
  - If I add a `name` then it renames only the first layer in the comma separated list (regardless of what layer is selected). For example, this:

    > ```
    > -merge-layers target="layer A, layer B" name="new layer"
    > ```

    ...renames layer A to "new layer" but does nothing at all to layer B. So for whatever reason it seems to ignore the layers after the first in the comma seperated list.
- I also tried using `name` like this:

  > ```
  > -merge-layers name="'layer A', 'layer B'"
  > ```

  ...which ran into this error, despite the fact I had used `-filter-fields` to remove these fields from the layers I was targeting:

  > Field missing from one or more layers: someField

  ...but I later discovered that this was because I'd misunderstood the `name` parameter: this was simply the name the new merged field would take, so since I had no `target` defined, it was trying to merge *all* layers and was picking up on errant fields in layers other than the ones I was trying to merge.
- I also tried using one layer name as a regular parameter and one as a `target=` but it didn't like that either:

  > ```
  > -merge-layers 'layer A' target="layer B"
  > ```

  ...gives this error:

  > Unexpected option: layer A
- I also tried two `target` options, but this doesn't work:

  > ```
  > -merge-layers target="layer A" target="layer B"
  > ```

All the usage examples I can find for `-merge-layers` use it to merge every layer.

What's the correct way to target and merge specific layers?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error I've found a crude workaround. I'm guessing it's some limitation of the browser-based GUI interface version of MapShaper that `target`'s comma seperated list doesn't work here for some reason?

The only method I could find that worked was:

- Rename the layers to be merged so they contain something no other layer name has. For example, adding `merge` to the start:

  > ```
  > -rename-layers 'merge layer A' target="layer A" 
  > -rename-layers 'merge layer B' target="layer B"
  > ```
- Use `-merge-layers` with a `*` wildcard in the `target` to target them all. Assuming we were trying to merge layer B into layer A:

  > ```
  > -merge-layers target="merge*" name="layer A"
  > ```

This does work and actually merges the layers into a new layer named "layer A".